# How to pass tuple results in one line

Tags: c#, tuples

I have a method that returns logLevel and string, and I call it like this:

```
Tuple<LogLevel, string> levelAndMessage = SomeMethod();
logger.Log(levelAndMessage.Item1, levelAndMessage.Item2);
```

I would like to change it to one line (to not declare a variable because sometimes scopes collide).

It should look something like:

```
logger.Log(SomeMethod().ToValueTuple());
```

However then I get error

> Argument 1: cannot convert from '(NLog.LogLevel, string)' to 'NLog.LogEventInfo' (CS1503)

How do I solve this?

Comment: "It should look something like:" **WHY** would you do that? To obfuscate your code? Make it harder to understand? Your current code looks pretty fine to me, I doubt you get it any clearer. Instead you can make it much uglier, Apart from that your `log`.method seems to expect two parameters, not a tuple.

Comment: As I said, because I cannot declare the same name variable everywhere, because scopes collide.

Comment: This is a typical [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). You're trying to solve problem X using solution Y. But Y is not the right solution. Describe what the *actual* problem is (something to do with scopes?!?) and im sure we can solve that.

Comment: Why not rename your variavbles to something that fits the variables purpose? At least something like `levelAndMessage1`, `levelAndMessage2` and so on, if you really can´t get anything better. But making your code fit in a single lines to reduce varibalename-collisions is worst solution one can think of.

Comment: And why's that the worst solution? Is it really better make up 20 different variable names and have a headache when/if you want to change the code even slightly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* write an extension method for Logger:

```
public static class LoggerExt
{
    public static void Log(this Logger logger, (LogLevel logLevel, string message) args)
    {
        logger.Log(args.logLevel, args.message);
    }
}
```

Then you could call it like you wanted:

```
var logger = new Logger();

// ...

logger.Log(SomeMethod());
```

Full compilable console app example:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public enum LogLevel
    {
        Low,
        Medium,
        High
    }

    public sealed class Logger
    {
        public void Log(LogLevel logLevel, string message)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

    public static class LoggerExt
    {
        public static void Log(this Logger logger, (LogLevel logLevel, string message) args)
        {
            logger.Log(args.logLevel, args.message);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var logger = new Logger();

            // ...

            logger.Log(SomeMethod());
        }

        public static (LogLevel logLevel, string message) SomeMethod()
        {
            return (LogLevel.High, "Some message");
        }
    }
}
```

However, without knowing the full context of where you want to use this, I can't really say that this is a good idea...

(Note that this answer is using C# 7.x tuples; if you are using an earlier version then you will have to adjust the parameter types to use `Tuple<>` as appropriate.)

Comment: Thank you. In my case it was `this ILoggerBase logger` to be extended.